# Lambda select many expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have a EmployeeTest as below and I want to "print each employee information" by lambda.
 I got `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` 
 
How can I fix my lambda expression?

```
 public class EmployeeTest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
        public List<int> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

        public static List<EmployeeTest> GetAllEmployees()
        {

            List<EmployeeTest> listEmployees = new List<EmployeeTest>
            {
                new EmployeeTest
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Skills = new List<string>{"ASP.NET","MVC","C#"},
                    PhoneNumbers = new List<int>{12345678,999999999}
                },
                new EmployeeTest
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Skills = new List<string>{"ASP.NET","MVC","SQL"},
                    PhoneNumbers = new List<int>{7777777,999999999}
                }
            };

            return listEmployees;

        }
    }

var result5 = EmployeeTest.GetAllEmployees().SelectMany(e2 => e2.PhoneNumbers, (Employee1, PhoneNumbers) => new {EmployeeID =  Employee1.ID,EmployeeSkills=Employee1.Skills.ToString(),EmployeeNum = PhoneNumbers });

 foreach (var V in result5)
          {
              Response.Write("ANS2:" + V.EmployeeID + "," + V.EmployeeSkills + "," + V.EmployeeNum + "<br/>");
          }
```

**output messages:**

> ANS1:Tom,ASP.NET
>  ANS1:Tom,MVC
>  ANS1:Tom,C#
>   ANS1:Mike,ASP.NET
>  ANS1:Mike,MVC
>  ANS1:Mike,SQL
>   ANS2:1,System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String],12345678<
>   ANS2:1,System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String],999999999
>   ANS2:2,System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String],7777777
>   ANS2:2,System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String],999999999

Comment: You haven't said *what* is wrong - please clarify your question, ideally with a [mcve]. Also, please pay more attention to your post layout... the source was all over the place before, and it's still *massively* scrolling over to the right. Horizontal scrolling makes a post very hard to read.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Please mentioned what issue you are getting like error message etc.

Comment: Skills is a list - you need to reference each of the items contained therein by index or enumeration. Skills[0], Skills[1] foreach(string Skill in Skills) or String.Join(",",Skills) - the latter of which seems to be the best alternative for your particular application.

Comment: I know Skills is a list but I want to print all Employees information in one lambda expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result5 = EmployeeTest.GetAllEmployees()
    .SelectMany(e2 => e2.PhoneNumbers, 
        (Employee1, PhoneNumbers) => new {
            EmployeeID = Employee1.ID,
            EmployeeSkills = Employee1.Skills,
            EmployeeNum = PhoneNumbers 
        }
    );
```

Then ...

```
foreach (var V in result5)
{
    Response.Write("ANS2:" + V.EmployeeID + "," + String.Join(",", V.EmployeeSkills) + "," + V.EmployeeNum + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Hi Shannon I got same result. I think problem is my lambda expression.

Comment: Yes - change the ToString() to String.Join(",",Employee1.Skills)

Comment: No - sorry. Hold on

Comment: Glad to help, Melo!